# Replace pattern in list in boost build/b2/bjam

Tags: replace, bjam, boost-build, b2

How can I replace a pattern in a list of strings in boost build ?

In GNU make that could be done using [substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs) for changing file extension, or [patsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using the rule "replace-list" from builtin module regex:

```
SWIG_SOURCES = [ glob *.i ] ;

import regex ;
SWIG_GENERATED_CPP_FILES = [ regex.replace-list $(SWIG_SOURCES) : \\.i : _wrap.cpp ] ;
```

Let's say the file `example_file.i` is located in the directory, its name will be added to the list `SWIG_SOURCES` by `glob` and will become `example_file_wrap.cpp` in the list `SWIG_GENERATED_CPP_FILES`;

The `\\` are used to mean that `.` is a litteral dot, without them `.` would match any character.

The `$` matches the end of the string.

More information in the [documentation of regex builtin](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/main/index.html#bbv2.reference.modules.regex)